# SQL Server - merge replication - 15 seconds delay between publisher and a subscriber

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

We have a client with a very small database (30 MB), the client has a merge replication between 2 physically connected stations with 10 GB communication cable. The SQL version is SQL Server standard edition 2014.

Let say table A is empty, when we make a table insert in the subscriber or the publisher, The synchronization time (inserting the data into the other side of the replication) is 15 seconds.

2 questions:

Is 15 seconds a reasonable time?
Is it possible to reach a level of synchronize time of a second?

Thanks